# Incorrect format in CSV excel file when loading JSON data into CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have some data in a JSON file, and I have used the code below to write them into csv file, but I found that the each word in a sentence has occupied one column, I want to store whole sentence in a single column.

This is the code:

```
for line in open('test1.json', 'r'):
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    data = json.loads(line)
    text = data["text"]
    filtered_text = clean_tweets(text)
    print(filtered_text)
    with open ('test1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
        csvWriter.writerow(filtered_text)
f.close()
```

[This is the output of csv file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTWrT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.writerow()` expects an iterable parameter.  Each item in the iterable is placed in a column.  Strings are iterable, hence you get a single character in each column.

Put the string(s) in a list:

```
csvWriter.writerow([filtered_text])
```

But since you seem to only have one column, using the `csv` module is unnecessary.  Just use:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(filtered_text + '\n') # add newline if needed
```

Another option:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(filtered_text,file=f) # will add the newline
```

Answer (score 0):

`csvWriter.writerow()` takes a list or similar of columns - you need to supply for example `csvWriter.writerow([tweet_id, filtered_tweet])`